# How do I avoid table a full table scan when converting date to timestamp in POSTGRES query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am querying a postgres database table that I only have read access to and cannot modify in any way. Long story short I need to run a query daily to pull records over several days. I have been going in each day and physically modifying the timestamp parameters. The table is about 40 million records and I am running pass through queries from a sql server to the linked server.

There is an index on the c_stime field which is a time stamp that I am trying to take advantage of, but when I perform a function over the field I kill that advantage. Here are some of my results:

```
select * from p_table where c_stime >= '2013-09-24 00:00:00.0000000' 
select * from p_table where c_stime >= current_date::timestamp
select * from p_table where c_stime >= current_date+ interval '0 hour'
```

First one runs in 10 seconds, second runs in 74 seconds, third runs in 88 seconds. Want something dynamic like the second/third with performance close to the first. Any help appreciated

Comment: How many of the 40 million rows are you retrieving?

Comment: 50-70k is the average

Comment: have you tried to look to the query plans?

Comment: Maybe that the first one runs faster just because it has cached the results (it was already executed before), while the others cannot be cached?

Answer (score 0):

First, check your query plans.  There may be surprises there.

Secondly, if the problem is as you say, I am surprised that this wouldn't have worked.  However you can use the pg_catalog.* functions to convert types and these are immutable (allowing the function to be run before the query is planned), so you could try:

```
select * from p_table where c_stime >= pg_catalog.timestamp(current_date);
```